# QtCreator AVD with Genymotion - incompatible ABI

Tags: android, qt, android-emulator

As x86 is dead on mobile I am of course using a ARM Kit in QtCreator, e.g. armeabi-v7a. The emulator of the Android SDK is horrible so I downloaded Genymotion to give it a try. However Genymotion seems to setup x86 devices so I end up with incompatible ABIs. I did not find any config.
How can I test with Genymotion?
Image: 1st device is from Android NDK, the other 2 are from Genymotion and do not work.

[image]

I already tried setting the environment variable as suggested at similar questions, without success:

[image]